# Realloc to structure in c

Tags: c

i have a problem with my realloc in the func add order its crash every time
someone can help me here

```
typedef struct
{
    char carname[30]; //car names
    int price; //the price of the car

}Vehicle;


typedef struct {
    int number;     // מספר הזמנה
    char *name;     // שם המזמין
    char ID[10];        // מספר זהות שלו
    int number_vehicles; // מספר הרכבים בהזמנה
    Vehicle * list;
    int sum_order;
}Order;



Order * add_orders(Order * firma, int * ordersize)// adding one more order
{

    int i, j;
    char temp[80];
    int newstart; // because we need to add one more order we need new start and it will be the old size of the number of orders
    newstart = *ordersize; //we just did it
    (*ordersize)++; // now we have new size +1 for the one more order

    for (i = newstart; i < *ordersize; i++) //same as the input function but this one start and finish from the new start and finish
    {
        printf("enter the ID of order number: %d\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &firma[i].number);
        while (getchar() != '\n');

        printf("enter the name of the client:\n");
        gets(temp);
        firma[i].name = (char*)malloc(strlen(temp) + 1 * sizeof(char));
        if (!firma[i].name)
        {
            printf("error\n");
            return 0;
        }
        strcpy(firma[i].name, temp);

        printf("enter the ID of client (length can only be 10):\n");
        gets(firma[i].ID);

        printf("enter how many vehicles you want in this order\n");
        scanf("%d", &firma[i].number_vehicles);
        firma[i].list = (Vehicle*)malloc(firma[i].number_vehicles * sizeof(Vehicle));

        if (!firma[i].list)
        {
            printf("error\n");
            return 0;
        }


        for (j = 0; j < firma[i].number_vehicles; j++)
        {
            while (getchar() != '\n');
            printf("enter the name of the vehicle number %d (only 30 chars):\n", j + 1);
            gets(firma[i].list[j].carname);
            printf("enter the price of the vehicle\n");
            scanf("%d", &firma[i].list[j].price);


        }

    }


    firma = (Order*)realloc(firma, (*ordersize * sizeof(Order))); //after we added the new order we do realloce for the new size for the struct
    if (!firma)//if failed
    {
        printf("error\n");
        return 0;
    }


}



int main()
{
    int i, j;
    char temp[80];
    char *str = NULL;
    int num, x, y;
    int number;
    int ordersize;
    int exit1 = 0;
    int exit2 = 0;
    int exit3 = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    int choose;
    Order *data = NULL; //pointer to the struct Order

printf("\nenter how many orders you want\n");
scanf("%d", &ordersize); //enter size of orders
data = (Order*)malloc(ordersize * sizeof(Order));//we allocte memory for the struct Order with pointer data

add_orders(data, &ordersize); //send it

return 0;
}
```

i have a problem with my realloc in the func add order its crash every time
someone can help me here

i have a problem with my realloc in the func add order its crash every time
someone can help me here

i have a problem with my realloc in the func add order its crash every time
someone can help me here

Comment: what exception or error you are getting

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5.2.2 Function calls 4 An argument may be an expression of any complete object type. In preparing for the call
to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the
corresponding argument. 93) A function may change the values of its parameters, but these changes cannot affect the values of the
arguments.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access out of bound for `firma`.

```
data = (Order*)malloc(ordersize * sizeof(Order));//we allocte memory for the struct Order with pointer data

add_orders(data, &ordersize); //send it
```

As you allocated memory of size `orderSize` and you access `firma[newstart]`.

```
newstart = *ordersize; //we just did it
(*ordersize)++; // now we have new size +1 for the one more order

for (i = newstart; i < *ordersize; i++) //same as the input function but this one start and finish from the new start and finish
{
    printf("enter the ID of order number: %d\n", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", &firma[i].number);
    while (getchar() != '\n');

    .....
 }
```

Thus first allocate more memory and access.

```
   newstart = *ordersize; //we just did it
   (*ordersize)++; // now we have new size +1 for the one more order

    firma = (Order*)realloc(firma, (*ordersize * sizeof(Order))); //after we added the new order we do realloce for the new size for the struct
    if (!firma)//if failed
    {
        printf("error\n");
        return 0;
    }

   for (i = newstart; i < *ordersize; i++) //same as the input function but this one start and finish from the new start and finish
   {
       printf("enter the ID of order number: %d\n", i + 1);
       scanf("%d", &firma[i].number);
        while (getchar() != '\n');

       .....
   }
```

---

> Note:: `firma` is local variable and allocating memory using `realloc`
>   in `addOrder` function has no effect on `data` variable in `main`
>   function. You may need to pass `data` using reference or return
>   updated value from function and assign it to `data`.

Comment: this is what i want to do i want to realloc data with firma what i need to change for that?

Comment: @bushez reallocate in the beginning of the function before the for loop. And return `firma` from function and from main `data = add_orders(data, &ordersize);`.

Comment: thank you very very much its working 100% and im really sory i just started to study structs and when i add functions to that its make me lose it alittle

Comment: Note that in C you cannot pass `data` by reference. All parameter passing in C is by-value.